# No schema found for the "org.eclipse.ui.menus" extension point

Tags: eclipse-rcp

The eclipse version I have installed is 10.0.1. When I add an extension point `"org.eclipse.ui.menus"` and when I click right to create a sub menu option, it only shows me a "Generic".

And it says that there are 3 warnings:

```
No schema found for the "org.eclipse.ui.menus" extension point
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: same problem..bro

Answer (score 34):

I met the same problem in Eclipse 4.3. It occurred because of the absence of source bundles for eclipse plugins. Resolved it by the following steps:

1. In Eclipse go to **Help > Install New Software...**
2. Update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3
3. Choose "**Eclipse RCP Target Components**" and press Next to install
   them

[image]

Comment: It worked for org.eclipse.ui.newWizards too, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, there is also a list of update sites here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites

Answer (score 8):

The schema for this extension is defined in the `org.eclipse.ui` bundle. Make sure you have added the appended source-bundle of the `org.eclipse.ui` (`org.eclipse.ui.source`) bundle in your target-platform. In this bundle the .exsd schema is located that is required to show the extension-specific forms.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to create a fresh workspace, instead of re-using the old eclipse-luna workspace ( during upgrade from eclipse-luna to eclipse-mars )